# AngularJS friendly return types of List and Dictionary with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, json, rest, angularjs, servicestack

AngularJS cannot bind to a value type model, as explained here:

- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1267
- [Modifying an array within an object that's displayed in a ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409815/modifying-an-array-within-an-object-thats-displayed-in-a-ng-repeat)

On the server side i've only a list of strings:

```
[Route("/path/{Id}", "GET, OPTIONS")]
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<string> SomeListItems { get; set; }
}
```

When i want to bind (**with ng-model to inputs**) to the list items via ng-repeat it does not work because ServiceStack serialize them as array of strings.

Is it possible to tell the ServiceStack serializer to **serialize and deserialize** Lists and Dictionaries as objects that can be used with AngularJS bindings?

E.g.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "someListItems": [
        { "value": "Item1" },
        { "value": "Item2" },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Same for Dictionaries.

The only solution i've found is to return a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` but that is very ugly on the server side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need to convert the list of string into associative array?  AngularJs can handle iterating over an array.

Here's a plnkr that demonstrates: http://plnkr.co/edit/TcXxSBkt7NBkqNJhkSE1

essentially, the server returns the object, and the property SomeListItems is an array.

use `ng-repeat` to iterate over them

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data.SomeListItems">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
```

I see a couple of solutions to this problem, either massage the data structure on the client or the server.

[Here's a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TcXxSBkt7NBkqNJhkSE1?p=preview) that shows converting the string array received from the server into an associative array so it can be edited on the client, and then re-converting back into a single dimension array for posting to the server.

Conversely, you could do this on the server.  If you declare SomeListItems as a list of dynamic, then you can assign anything you want to it, including anonymous objects, which the ServiceStack serializer should be able to handle (i haven't tested, this, but i think it will work).

```
[Route("/path/{Id}", "GET, OPTIONS")]
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<dynamic> SomeListItems { get; set; }
}

// in a controller or service
var model = new MyModel() { Id = 1 };
model.SomeListItems =  new List<dynamic> {
  new { Key = 1, Value = "foo }, new {Key = 2, Value = "bar" }
}; // this should serialize to JSON as { Id: 1, SomeListItems: [ {Key: 1, Value: 'foo'}, {Key:2, Value = 'bar'}]}; which angular can handle nicely
```

alternatively, you could specify a custom class that is less verbose than `KeyValuePair<string, string>`

```
public class JsonPayload
{ // yes, it's just a KVP, but it's much more concise
  public string Key {get;set;}
  public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

and then redefine your model

```
[Route("/path/{Id}", "GET, OPTIONS")]
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<JsonPayload> SomeListItems { get; set; }
}
```

this is a bit more verbose than using dynamics but the JSON serialization should definitely be able to handle this.

Comment: Thans for your answer. Yes one-way binding works well, but i want to bind with ng-model to inputs. Sorry if this was not clear in my question.