# How to update a model within your collection array from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I understand that Angular really naturally allows user interactions to update a model. In fact, there are lots of questions about it already on SO, [here's one of those questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409815/modifying-an-array-within-an-object-thats-displayed-in-a-ng-repeat).

In that scenario, the user must interact with the model through the view.

But how can I modify a model in the collection as a result of something programmatic from the controller? for instance... lets say I'm building a loader of some kind with a unique progress number associated with each loader. When the user starts to load something, the load event is added to the collection of past load events. and now, I want to make some updates to the loader.progress via ajax.

So the view would show something like this:

```
Loading Assets:
=====================================
Loader 1 ------------ 53%
Loader 2 ------------------------ 91%
Loader 3 -- 9%
Loader 4 --------- 43%
```

and the collection of models is something like this:

```
$scope.loaders = [
    { asset: "somePicture.jpg", progress: 53 },
    { asset: "movie.mov", progress: 91 },
    { asset: "someProgram.torrent", progress: 9 },
    { asset: "etc.txt", progress: 43 }
];
```

and when I first initiate a new loader, i would add it to the collection this way:

```
$scope.loaders.push({ asset: "reallyCoolSong.mp3", progress: 0 });
```

And naturally, the next step would be to update `reallyCoolSong.mp3`'s progress after ajax functions complete.

How do I do that?

Comment: I think you may be over complicating things in your head.  All you need to do is update the property of the object that you want to be updated in the view and it will automatically cause the view to refresh anywhere you are binding to that property.  So what you describe would just work.  If you are using $http angular will automatically flag for a digest cycle by calling apply.  If you are doing something outside of the angular services that is async you just call $scope.$apply() when it is done.

Comment: but there literally is no way for me to update from the view... the user is not "updating" the progress of the download... the download itself is being updated by ajax. therefore, from the controller, i'd need to maintain the array index of some model in `$scope.loaders` and then update it by saying `$scope.loaders[index].progress = 12`?

Comment: You don't need to update from the view. Have you tried your solution? That to me seems the right way. Your ajax response triggers a function which updates the progress of the loader. Because there is no user interaction, you'll probably need to use $scope.$apply

Comment: Yes, I can do that, however, that means I must assume the array indices do not change, which I'm not able to guarantee. also, since angular has a ton of built in methods for managing models, it seems weird to me that i'd have to start manually maintaining my own index numbers for this... and it speaks to the issue of spotty maintainability from the development perspective

Comment: I understand your issue with maintaining the indices for each of the AJAX calls.  It might be worthwhile to wrap up the code that does the AJAX call and the progress bar into a custom directive.  This way each instance of the directive would make the AJAX call and update it's own isolated scope.  Building the directive may be a bit more work but will allow you to re-use the component.

Comment: @shaunhusain +1 on that solution

Comment: Here's another solution http://plnkr.co/edit/Ve508uRyrEL8DIaHRIzI

Comment: @calebboyd where did you find this? did you write it yourself? if so, please add that as an answer, because its a very good solution.

Comment: Yeah, I added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keeping in-line with OO, you could have a loading bar object in a factory. That uses a service like $http or $.ajax, in a method on itself to update, forgoing the need to track indices. If you use `$.ajax` Just know that you'll need to use

```
if(!$rootScope.$$phase)$rootScope.$apply()
```

method to fire off a digest cycle from the `$.ajax`'s xhr progress event. Or maybe you already have a mechanism for that.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ve508uRyrEL8DIaHRIzI) with the general idea

Answer (score 2):

I setup a demo you should be able to build on... I'm just using $timeout to simplify things but that could be where you update progress based on the AJAX call.

```
// Code goes here

angular.module("myApp",["ui.bootstrap"]).directive("progressLoader", function($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {file:"@"},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.progress = 0;
      function updateProgress(){
        scope.progress++;
        if(scope.progress<100)
          $timeout(updateProgress,100);
      }
      updateProgress();

    },
    template: "<div>{{file}}</div><progressbar value=\"progress\"></progressbar>"
  }  
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/f2FBBiMYtA6YU46uKbvb?p=preview